# Handle EventEmitter error in event binding

Tags: angular

Suppose I have this EventEmitter in a child component:

```
export class ImageUploadComponent {
    ...
    @Output() imageDataEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
    ...
}
```

This child component, depending on what happens may emit something or generate an error:

```
...
this.imageDataEvent.emit('good');
...
this.imageDataEvent.error('wrong');
```

The parent component listens to it through event binding:

```
<app-image-upload (imageDataEvent)="onImageUpload($event)"></app-image-upload>
```

When 'good' is emitted, onImageUpload is called on parent component and $event contains 'good'.

How to handle the case of 'wrong'? How can I know when the event is an error? How exactly event binding works for good/bad events?

Comment: Shouldn't you check to see with some logic before emitting the event? So it only emits a correct 'good' event at all times?

Comment: If you want to handle special case, you should add such logic in `onImageUpload` method. If you want to avoid special case, you emit your `imageDataEvent` only when it should be emitted.

Comment: As a side-note, consider using duck-typing by writing `@Output() imageDataEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();` to improve readibility.

Comment: Thank you, yes of course I may rewrite it in a different way, but since EventEmitter extends Subject which extends Observable, I know that Observables handle differently a 'next' value and an 'error' value when subscribing. With event binding, I expect that the parent component subscribes to the "Observable interface part" (so to speak), and it handles 'next' value. My question is how to handle the 'error' value of the "Observable interface part" of the EventEmitter in event binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular's `EventEmitter`s are actually an extension of `Observable`s.

It's been said that it's generally best practice to not handle errors in `@Output`s. However, taking advantage of `Observable` error streams can lead to some pretty elegant code, and having access to `Observable` operators has some very obvious benefits.

The only difference is that Angular's template binding to an `Output` event handles the `Observable` subscription to the `EventEmitter` internally. The solution is to forego the template binding and just subscribe to the component property manually:

```
<app-image-upload #upload></app-image-upload>
```

in your parent component:

```
@ViewChild('upload') upload: AppImageUploadComponent; 

ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.upload.imageDataEvent.subscribe(
        event => console.log('Emission!'),
        err => console.error(`D'oh!`),
        () => console.log('Complete!')
    );

}
```

This also allows you to use `catch` or any other Observable operators that you'd need.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!